# Busy beaver in a coin

Tags: code-golf, random, open-ended-function, busy-beaver

\$BB\$ is the [busy beaver function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver), an uncomputable function.
Write a program which when given an integer \$n\$ as input, will output \$BB(n)\$, with at least \$\frac 2 3\$ probability. You can do whatever (return something wrong, infinite loop, explode, etc.) in other cases.

To help you compute it, you're given a function that randomly returns 0 or 1 (false or true, etc.). You can decide the exact probability that it returns 0, but all returns of calls should be independent.

Shortest code wins.

## Notes

- The exact definition of BB doesn't matter much so not clearly defined above.
- If you encode some code into the randomness, they add nothing to length of your solution(actually it's hard to define code and data here). You should, when constructing the coin, show the code, though.

Comment: As touched on the busy beaver function is not a singular function.  It's exact values depend on what model of computation we use.  E.g. the busy beaver function *for a two symbol single tape Turing machine*.  You should make it clear in the challenge, what is required of answers here.

Comment: so whats the output or input if there's any?

Comment: It might be clearer to just say require any function that grows faster than all computable functions and give the busy beaver function as an example.  BB functions are a rather simple example of that and so pretty much anyone would end up implementing some BB.

Comment: @WheatWizard Reimplementing BB somehow using the randomness is likely longer than fetching one

Comment: How is this possible? As I understand it, this would mean that we can solve the halting problem with an arbitrarily small chance of failure, which seems impossible. Proof: given a program `p` use a busy beaver number to give an upper bound for time before halting, then simulate, and decide if the program halts. By doing the busy beaver calculation in parallel multiple times, we can make the chance of failure arbitrarily small. The fact that the calculation might not halt doesn't matter, since we can just wait for half of the calculations to terminate.

Comment: @AnttiP You're given the randomness, which store infinite bits of info

Comment: @l4m2 Ah, I see, you have to use an uncomputable number as the probability right? Otherwise I don't see how it would work (50/50 doesn't work right?)

Comment: @l4m2 If you're meant to have the probability be uncomputable and output the probability itself, you should specify that. Right now it just reads that given some n and the probability of your choosing, output.... something, 2/3 of the time. Should this be tagged [open-ended-function]? An example might help

Comment: @thejonymyster Every solution must output BB(n) for 2/3 probable so it's not [open-ended-function]

Comment: but "The exact definition of BB doesn't matter much so not clearly defined above". If it's not open ended, shouldn't BB(n) be explicitly defined?

Comment: @thejonymyster Because we won't get the exact value of BB(n) and just express them as `BB(n)`, and if we just symbolize it then it's exact definition is not important

Comment: I guess I just don't get this.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <strike>68</strike> 66 bytes

```python
lambda x:eval(sum(r()for _ in"X"*4**900).to_bytes(225,"big")[:99])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BasJQEEX3/YqQVRJKeTNz582MXyKISEJtK6iRmIp@fXztol1cuJtzOJfH/DWexS/Tshz70/DeV/fV/tYfm@v3qZma9mOcql11ONfrukPXRUrt2zzuhse8vzbM@loPh8@63awitu3ySxIJGCxmpplN7GfIkcVCc2JL0IwIB5MjNEDkpg4KcidoYleFkBATA8hKUiyqxcqZPAWRkWqBhLn8gKuBX/7LNP2FMZWwJw)

-2 bytes thanks to @l4m2

`r` is the random function. Its probability of outputting one encodes a 99-byte code snippet, which is evaluated. This code snippet can then read much more data from the randomness, and basically you can encode any program you want into the randomness stream.

[Here is a practical demonstration](https://tio.run/##VU5dC4MwDHzvrwh9SsomzH0gMv0lA1HWuoJtpXZDf72rUx/2EJLLXS7XT@Hl7Dnr/ay8M@Br@4xNm975AIKZoYUCGj5ypuOgbUgWXdVMQQ4Y2QNvdMuJ@ch2tWmedf4zidVKTAWm15sQnbSLmOAIJyK4F5AKvQCmise83sGYy0/dIQ5vgx5JOQ9V/Air1UUI3G1ERkRl@YeT4LZU@3aLRnPvY25UmMb5Cw)

Example (less than) 99-byte snippet:

```python
eval((sum(r()for _ in"X"*2**88001)>>80000).to_bytes(1000,"big")[99:])
```

As you can see, there is no limit to what kind of code we can run

To actually solve the busy beaver problem, the rest of the randomness is dedicated to just storing the answers to the question (that is, the busy beaver numbers).

The probability of failure depends on the first calculation. I *think* it succeeds with more than 2/3 probability, but i could be wrong. I'll check and add a proof later. Nevertheless, if it fails the criteria, this only results in some adjusting to the magic constants.

For the encoding of the busy beaver numbers, we first use the following encoding (I'm using a list of primes as an example)

`[2,3,5,7,...]`

Is converted into

`110111011111011111110...`

Finally, in order to account for the table-maker's dilemma, we replace`1` with `10` and `0` with `01`, resulting in
`101001101010011010101010011010101010101001...`

Then we execute the following code:

```python
def get_raw_bit(p):
 # A lot of tries
 tries = 2**(2**p)
 hits = sum(r() for _ in range(2**tries))
 hits >> (tries - p)
def get_bit(p):
 code_len = 1000
 get_bit(code_len + 2*p)
pos = 0
p = -1
while pos < x:
 count = 0
 while get_bit(p:=p + 1):
  count+= 1
print(count)
```

Comment: Seems you need infinite layers of such construction and use form `[BB(5)] if x==5 else [eval]`

Comment: Can you not shr 997 and comment the quite random part?

Comment: @l4m2 RE: `[BB(5)] if x==5 else [eval]` No, not really. After the first two layers or so, you can make a reader function that reads the bitstream encoded in the randomness. The bitstream can have the following format: "110111011111110111111111110...". This would encode the list [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...] for example. Instead of the primes you encode the busy beaver numbers. You can do `[BB(5)] if x==5 else [eval]` but it's a bit more complicated. You can't directly store the numbers in decimal, because they get so big so fast. The comment idea is good though

Comment: If you can't fit the number in this layer, just go to next layer where longer code is allowed. This is easier, at least when rule requires to show the code

Comment: So that requires the first layer of code be short enough, s.t. the random part is not that long and unlikely contain these chars

Comment: @l4m2 I did the calculations, it doesn't work. There are 3 characters that break the comment, namely the null byte, the line feed, and the carriage return. This means that the evaluated string can only contain 34 totally random characters, before the chance of the comment breaking becomes over 2/3. A good rule of thumb is that the length of the non-random part is roughly the same as the random part. So we can only use 34 characters for the code, which doesn't help at all.

Comment: [Slicing after `to_bytes` seems 2 bytes shorter](https://tio.run/##RY7BasJQEEX3/YqQVRJKeTNz582MXyKUIgm1KqiRmEr9@vTpxsWFuzmHc7nP@/EsfpmW5difhu@@@lttb/2xuf6emqlpf8ap2lSHc72uO3Sdp9R@zONmuM/ba8MpvdfDYVe3n6uIr3Z5kkQCBouZaWYTeww5slhoTmwJmhHhYHKEBojc1EFB7gRN7KoQEmJiAFlJikW1WDmTpyAyUi2QMJcfcDXw26tMX2FMJewf)